# Why is my SATA drive running at 728 megabytes per second if the real-world limit is 600 megabytes per second?

Tags: sata

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/923621/167207) it should not be performing like this but here it is doing exactly that!

[image: Screenshot of DDRESCUE showing performance metric]

Comment: dd could be skipping zeroed or TRIMed areas of disk. What kind of disk are you copying from or to? Otherwise it could be using caching: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691372/dd-faster-than-it-should-be

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... copy and paste the text instead

Comment: What kind of SATA drive is this? (Specifically, why does it say "non-tried: 9223 petabytes")?

Comment: 1.   It’s not skipping trimmed areas

2. Sorry

3. It’s copying from /dev/zero to an raid array.  The source of this strangeness was BTRFS compression.  The huge size reported by ddrescue was a result of it being unable to read the size of the fake file

Answer (score 3):

#### It was BTRFS compression.

And since I was writing all zeros 3.5 TiB of zeros compressed to around 90 GiB and the actual throughput was significantly lower than I was lead to believe by the performance metrics.

Comment: Great self-solved answer!